# Is there a PHP setting that sets whether you can index the result of a function?

Tags: php, configuration, xdebug

I have two servers. They are both running php 5.3.3. This code works on one server and returns a syntax error on the other. Is there a php ini setting that affects this behaviour? I can't find anything related in the PHP documentation, but I may be looking in the wrong place.

### Server 1

```
> php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Sep 23 2010 14:15:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by Derick Rethans

php > echo explode(" ", " foo ")[1];
foo
```

### Server 2

```
> php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jan 31 2011 15:57:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

php > echo explode(" ", " foo ")[1];
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in php shell code on line 1
```

Another idea: PHP on both servers is custom-compiled, so it could also be a different compile flag.

Comment: You may try get differences betwen php.ini from two servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! I figured it out.

We installed Facebook's XHP to profile our development server. This syntax (which is quite elegant) was added in in the PHP module. Here's a diff of the php.ini file between server 1 and 2:

```
> ; XHP https://github.com/facebook/xhp/wiki/Building-XHP
> extension=xhp.so
> ; adds support for the [] operator on the return value of a function
> xhp.idx_expr = 1
> ;  Tracking errors in XHP applications is very difficult without annotations.
> xhp.include_debug = 1
```

I like this syntax, so I'll probably install XHP on the other server. Thanks for the help Michas for suggesting I diff the ini files.

Comment: Another suggestion here could be diff phpinfo output as text from `php -i` or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

No.

PHP doesn't support this syntax. [It's on the trunk](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html), but not yet released (as of PHP 5.3.3).

I have no idea how it's working on your first server, but perhaps this "Xdebug" is making a difference?